# Docker apt-get update don't work

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt-get

When I run `docker run --rm ubuntu apt-get update`, i have this error on my laptop. But command `docker run --rm debian:jessie ping -c 5 google.com` works correctly.

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Can you try `docker run --rm ubuntu curl -fSL http://archive.ubuntu.com/`?

Comment: @EricCitaire No. I don't use proxy.

~ docker run --rm ubuntu curl -fSL http://archive.ubuntu.com/

container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"curl\": executable file not found in $PATH"

docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"curl\": executable file not found in $PATH".

Comment: Ok, `curl` isn't installed. Try `docker run --rm ubuntu wget -v http://archive.ubuntu.com/`

Comment: Command `docker run --rm ubuntu wget -v http://archive.ubuntu.com/` returns the same error. `wget` isn't installed. Ubuntu:latest image

Comment: Ok... Try `docker run --rm curl curl -fSL http://archive.ubuntu.com/`.

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com port 80: Connection refused

Comment: How is this question on-topic here regardless? Our focus is *software development* -- writing code. "Code" includes Dockerfiles, yes, but there's no Dockerfile here, only information applicable to system-level debugging -- which is to say, [unix.se] SE content.

Comment: This may be related to this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23910). It is a DNS issue with docker and can be fixed by editing `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and adding IP addresses for Docker to resolve. Happened to me running a Docker container inside another Docker container, which then failed for the above reasons stated in the issue.

Comment: I think it isn't a DNS issue because the ip adress is correct (91.189.88.152).